# Passing variables to a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I've a select option list and a jstree object and I'd like to pass the user choices to a django view to process it and get the response. I'm surely doing something wrong but I don't know how to solve it. I can get the values in the scheduler view, but the template never loads, it stays in the previous view(the one who generated the template posted below).

```
<html>
<body>
<select  id="opt" name="numbers">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input id="goButton" value="Go!" class="btn small info" />

<div id="demo2" class="demo">
    <ul>
    {% for car_type, cs in cars.items %}
        <li>
            <a>{{ car_type }}</a>
                <ul>
                    {% for c in cs %}
                        <li><a id="{{c.0}}">{{c.1}}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#demo2").jstree({ 
             .........

        function submitMe(){ 
            var checked_ids = new Array();
            var car_amount = $("select option:selected").val();
            $("#demo2").jstree("get_checked",null,true).each 
                (function (index,value) {
                    if (value.children[2].id) { 
                        checked_ids.push(value.children[2].id); 
                    }
                });
            var car_ids = checked_ids.join(" ");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{% url scheduler %}",
                data: {'car_ids': car_ids, 'car': car_amount},
                dataType: "json"
            });
        };

        $("#goButton").click(function() {
            submitMe();
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py(scheduler):

```
def scheduler(request):

    if request.is_ajax():
        c_ids = request.POST['car_ids'].split(" ")
        cars = request.POST['car']
        .......

    context = {
        'cars' : cars, 
    }
    return render_to_response(
        'scheduler.html',
         context,
         context_instance = RequestContext(request),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view returns a rendered template, but your Ajax doesn't do anything with it.

If you just want the button to take the user to a new page, you shouldn't use Ajax at all. Just put the values into a form and make the button a normal `input type="submit"`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, as you see in the code, I've to first do some thing with the values before sending them. I was thinking of using jquery .submit(), but I don't know how to redirect it to the new view with the data appended.

Comment: @rodringo, submit is a form method.  You would give your form an action and when you call submit on it it will use the method you specify to submit to the action url.  Ex `<form method='POST' action='/your_view/'  >`